# How to write and read binary data to file in C with posix library using file descriptors?

Tags: c, posix, binaryfiles, file-writing

I would like to write some binary data into file "something.dat" using functions write() and read(). I get file descriptor as argument. The goal is to write binary data separated by ',': data,data1,data2,data3 and then read it again from binary file. I am not allowed to use fopen(), fwrite() and fread().

I have searched for binary examples, but mostly all others examples are with file pointers or functions that are not a option. Can i get a simple example how to do this? I can do the rest myself.

Comment: If you write binary data, how do you know that ',' is your separator or part of the data?

Comment: _"binary data separated by ',' "_: that is somewhat contradictory. [Edit] and explain more thoroughly what you're trying to achieve. Also read this: [ask]

Comment: If you're able to resolve the problem using the stdio functions `fopen`, `fwrite` and `fread`, then you should be able to resolve it with the posix functions `open`, `creat`, `read` and `write` which are pretty similar..

Comment: read and write ***are*** for binary data. (because there isn't binary data and not-binary data. there's just data)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Have you looked at the documentation for those functions?

Comment: It is either all binary, or none of it is binary.  You cannot have _"comma separated binary data"_ without some sort of encoding, and what would be the point?  All data stored is _binary_, it is a matter of what it _represents_.  The binary sequence 0010 1100 for example represents the value 44 decimal, but it also represents  ASCII comma.  The only way to have comma-separated binary is if you could guarantee that your binary did not contain 0010 1100.  Or as I say use some sort of encoding - not raw binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The POSIX `read()`/`write()` functions are implicitly binary.  Just write the data:

```
uint8_t data[] = { 0x00, 0xFF, 0xDE } ;
ssize_t written = write( fd, data, sizeof(data) ) ;
```

It seems that you may be confused by the `"b"`/`"t"` open modes of `fopen()`.  That is not relevant here - it is just binary.  Even with the `"t"` (text) open mode only affects line-end translation and on platforms where the line-end convention is LF (such as Linux), it has no effect at all.

The concept of *comma-separated binary* data in your "goal" is however flawed. Text files do not contain glyphs, they comprise of *binary* codes representing characters that the platform may render as glyphs - on a display for example.

Comma is represented by the binary sequence 0010 1100 (44 decimal), so you cannot comma-separate binary data and distinguish the commas from any other binary data.